# Git, Create a clone/fork but keeping my projects "origin-parts" updated from the source?

Tags: git, clone, fork

This might seem like a wierd thing.. or maybe Im not just sure of what the correct therm of what Im trying to achive is..
But basically what I would like to do is to copy or fork a project, and then add my own "layer" of stuff to my clone/fork, but I still would like to be able to just pull down the latest changes from the cloned/forked project..

So lets for instance say that I have found a great project on github thats open source and etc.. I then clone it and start to extend that project in my own clone, but a few weeks later the project that I cloned releases some new updates.. I would then like to just simply pull down the changes to my cloned project..

Is this possible somehow?
I know that one way would be to manually add the changes, but that doesn't seem very efficient..

Br,
Inx

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you have your own remote for your version of the clone? 2. Are you willing to use git on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can have two remotes for your git repo. Here is an example using a popular GitHub repository.

### Setup two remotes for one local repo

```
> git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
> git remote add mine git@github.com:bigfont/my-bootstrap.git
> git remote -v

mine    git@github.com:bigfont/my-bootstrap.git (fetch)
mine    git@github.com:bigfont/my-bootstrap.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap (push)
```

### Pull from the original remote

```
> git pull origin master
```

### Push or pull with your remote

```
> git pull mine master
> git push mine master
```

The syntax here is `git push <remote> <branch>`.

### Simplify things

You also might want to change the default push/pull location by running `git branch --set-upstream-to mine/master`. That way you can run `git push` or `git pull` for your remote and use the longer syntax when pulling from the original remote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Keep the original remote and fetch changes from time to time

```
git fetch <the remote name I gave to the original open-source project>
```

When there are updates you will probably want to do rebase or merge of your branches on top of the upstream changes.

It will quickly get messy though if you are changing same files as those changed upstream.